# find whitespace in hyperlinks with php and fix them

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have hyperlinks entered by users that have been justified. This has created the following scenario in my html:

```
<a href="http://  www.  web site  link  .com  ">Website link bro  ken  </a>
```

How can I use php to fix this on page load or in a script I run on my database to achieve this:

```
<a href="http://www.websitelink.com">Website link bro   ken</a> (the link text I guess is impossible to fix without checkning if parts of words could fit together - as long as the link works, the on screen justification will have to pass.
```

Please bear in mind that these occurances are within large bodies of text. So searching for the spaces would begin with finding each link and then 'repairing' it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function replaceSpaces( $in ) {
 return preg_replace( "/ /", "", $in );
} 

$link = preg_replace( "/href=\"[^\"]+\"/ie", " replaceSpaces( '\$0' )", $link );
```

Edited - thx for comments - my mistake

Comment: Almost. Use `'$0'` in the replacement expression, else it will lose the `href="` prefix. And replaceSpaces might better use str_replace, or otherwise use `/\s+/` to find all whitespace variants.

Comment: You don't need regular expression inside your function. A normal `str_replace` works too.

Comment: I preffer to use regular expression for cases when i need to update functionality ( eg i need to drop something else )

Comment: this does seem to work but urls are replaced with \" i.e. <a href=\"http://www.websitelink.com\">Website Link</a> - how to remove the \ and just have <a href="http://www.websitelink.com">Website Link</a>

Comment: function replaceBlankSpacesinURL($content) {
$content = preg_replace( "/href=\"[^\"]+\"/ie", " replaceSpaces( '\$0' )", $content );
return stripslashes($content);
}